# Ranking Nested Array on Number Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

My first question on this topic was answered and it helped me move forward so I apologize if this seems like it's duplicate. I've moved forward from the 1st example and am now trying to Rank elements in a nested array based on values at postion (1) in each element of the nested array. The following works great with a number array.

```
function mySorting(a, b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : (b < a ? -1 : 1)
}

var myArray = [28, 92, 12, 12, 2];
myArray.sort(mySorting);

var ranks = $.grep(myArray, function(item, idx) {
    return item != myArray[idx - 1];
}).reverse();



$.each(myArray, function(idx, item) {
    var rank= $.inArray( item, ranks)+1;
    $('body').append('Rank of '+item+ ' is '+ rank+'<br>')

})​
```

My problem is when I change the array to:

```
var myArray = [["textA",28], ["textB",92], ["textC",12], ["textD",12], ["textE",2]];
```

my sorting function no longer works. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction? I would like to sort "myArray" based of the number value in each nested element.

Thanks much once again in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments passed to the sorting function are whatever is contained in the array to be sorted.  Your new array contains two-element arrays, so that's what the sorting function will receive when you sort the array.

You say you want to sort the two-element arrays according to their second element.  To do that, you should change your sorting function to look like this:

```
function mySorting(a, b) {
    return a[1] == b[1] ? 0 : (b[1] < a[1] ? -1 : 1)
}
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to assign the same rank to all arrays with the same second element, you'll also need to modify the rest of your code to only consider the second element when comparing arrays.  Actually, it would probably be easiest to keep the sorting as it was, but just throw away everything but the second element before ranking the arrays:

```
function toSortKey(item) {
    return item[1];
}

function mySorting(a, b) {
    return a == b ? 0 : ( b < a ? -1 : 1 );
}

var myArray = [["textA",28], ["textB",92], ["textC",12], ["textD",12], ["textE",2]];

var sortKeys = $.map(myArray, toSortKey);
sortKeys.sort(mySorting);

var ranks = $.grep(sortKeys, function(item, idx) {
    return item != sortKeys[idx - 1];
}).reverse();

$.each(myArray, function(idx, item) {
    var rank = $.inArray( toSortKey(item), ranks ) + 1;
    $('body').append('Rank of ' + item + ' is ' + rank + '<br>')
})​;
```

Comment: ive tried this in the past and while it still sorts the items in the array it no longer accounts for ties which is my main problem.

Comment: So what do you want to do in the case of ties?

Comment: Id like it to perform the same functionality as the example in my original post which if theres a tie it assigns the same rank value to those items based on their rank. check the following fiddle if you want to see the proper return values. http://jsfiddle.net/XWs5j/1/ You can see the difference with a nested array at the following fiddle.(not working as intended) http://jsfiddle.net/pxGyj/1/

Comment: Thank you Ilmari. Nice to meet you and your help is greatly appreciated.